# Error while calling Api using Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, alamofire, swift4, swifty-json

I am calling an api using Alamofire and its a post request. The error doesnt come always. It comes up only when the api is called after quite some time. After that error state, the same api works perfectly.

[image]

This is the code that i am using

```
func getAuthTokenFromServer(completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void)
{
    self.showActivityIndicator()

    let deviceUDID      =   UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString

    let deviceModel     =   UIDevice.current.model.description

    let deviceOS        =   UIDevice.current.systemVersion

    let deviceName      =   UIDevice.current.name

    let webURL: String  =   "<SOME URL>"

    let params          =   ["deviceId": deviceUDID, "deviceType": deviceModel, "deviceOS": deviceOS, "deviceName": deviceName] as [String : Any]

    debugPrint(params)

    Alamofire.request(webURL, method: .post , parameters: params,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result
        {
        case .success:

            debugPrint(response)

            if let json = response.result.value
            {
                var jsonObj                 = JSON(json)

                print(jsonObj)

                let responseCode       = (jsonObj["response"]["code"]).stringValue

                print(responseCode)

                if (responseCode == "1000")
                {
                    self.firstTextView.text = "\(jsonObj)"
                    completion(true)
                    self.hideActivityIndicator()
                }
                else
                {
                    SetDefaultWrappers().showAlert(info: (jsonObj["response"]["message"]).stringValue, viewController: self)
                    completion(true)
                    self.hideActivityIndicator()
                }
            }
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            debugPrint(response)
            self.hideActivityIndicator()
            completion(true)
            SetDefaultWrappers().showAlert(info: error.localizedDescription, viewController: self) // The alert in the question is called from here
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me in solving this issue. I am using Alamofire to call api and SwiftJSON to parse data.

Comment: Try to log response from the server, so when JSON serialization fails log  response String, that way you will see what you are trying to serialize and will most likely find that it is not in JSON format

Comment: Also post the code where you are making the request and when the `UIAlertView` is displayed

Comment: @Ladislav Added code in the question

Comment: Did you check what you get back from this line `debugPrint(response)`